How to get and edit the shape size of an Unreal Control Shape using Python
In Unreal 5, I am trying to run a script that gets a list of all controls in a Control Rig, then gets the size of the shape controllers so I can resize them by a multiple. I can get the list of all controls, but editing the shape sizes is beyond me.
import unreal
blueprint = unreal.load_object(name = '[location]', outer = None)
library = blueprint.get_local_function_library()
library_controller = blueprint.get_controller(library)
hierarchy = blueprint.hierarchy
lista = hierarchy.get_controls(traverse=True)
print(lista)


for ala in lista:
    print(ala)

Output:
LogPython: <Struct 'RigElementKey' (0x000006607CE55AD0) {type: Control, name: "global_ctrl"}>
LogPython: <Struct 'RigElementKey' (0x000006607CE53810) {type: Control, name: "root_ctrl"}>
LogPython: <Struct 'RigElementKey' (0x000006607CE57DB0) {type: Control, name: "body_offset_ctrl"}>
LogPython: <Struct 'RigElementKey' (0x000006607CE597C0) {type: Control, name: "thigh_l_fk_ctrl"}>
LogPython: <Struct 'RigElementKey' (0x000006607CE57BE0) {type: Control, name: "calf_l_fk_ctrl"}>
LogPython: <Struct 'RigElementKey' (0x000006607CE57B00) {type: Control, name: "foot_l_fk_ctrl"}>
...

Now, I do know how to change the values manually, but I want to be able to get the values then multiply them, and do it as part of my loop.
hierarchy_controller = hierarchy.get_controller()
hierarchy.set_control_shape_transform(unreal.RigElementKey(type=unreal.RigElementType.CONTROL, name='global_ctrl'), unreal.Transform(scale=[50.000000,150.000000,1.000000]), True)
hierarchy.set_control_shape_transform(unreal.RigElementKey(type=unreal.RigElementType.CONTROL, name='root_ctrl'), unreal.Transform(scale=[50.000000,250.000000,1.000000]), True)

So, algorithm of I want:
import unreal
blueprint = unreal.load_object(name = '[location]', outer = None)
library = blueprint.get_local_function_library()
library_controller = blueprint.get_controller(library)
hierarchy = blueprint.hierarchy
lista = hierarchy.get_controls(traverse=True)
print(lista)

    
for ala in lista:
    # ~ represents an algorithm instead of a true piece of code
    ~shape_size = ala.getshapescale()
    ~shape_size_new = shape_size*5
    ~hierarchy.set_control_shape_transform(
      unreal.RigElementKey(type=unreal.RigElementType.CONTROL,
      name=ala.name),
      unreal.Transform(scale=
      [shape_size_new.x, shape_size_new.y, shape_size_new.z]), True)


I was able to figure it out.
import unreal
blueprint = unreal.load_object(name = '[location]', outer = None)
library = blueprint.get_local_function_library()
library_controller = blueprint.get_controller(library)
hierarchy = blueprint.hierarchy
lista = hierarchy.get_controls(traverse=True)

for ala in lista:
    nm = ala.name

    val = hierarchy.get_global_control_shape_transform(
          unreal.RigElementKey(
          type=unreal.RigElementType.CONTROL, name=nm), initial=False)

    scal = val.scale3d
    scal2 = scal * 7.5

    tgt_scl = scal2
    
    hierarchy.set_control_shape_transform(
      unreal.RigElementKey(type=unreal.RigElementType.CONTROL, name=nm), 
      unreal.Transform(scale=[tgt_scl.x, tgt_scl.y, tgt_scl.z]), True)

